# To Gain further knowledge on Economics(Undergraduate)

Tags: reference-request

I am currently in high school, but my textbook doesn't appropriately style the subject as it is. So is there some standard author's book which I can follow with math(log, derivative)?

***EDIT***

The branch would be macroeconomics(mostly keynesian theories) and microeconomics, but the math should preferrably be little rigourous because it is not so in my textbook. Also the math should be introductory calculus or anything below that.

Comment: Economics is quite broad. Can you maybe narrow it down, what branch of Economics are you interested in? Also, I think there are several similar questions on this site, [have a look around](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+book+).

Comment: @Giskard the branch would be macroeconomics(mostly keynesian theories) and microeconomics, but the math should preferrably be little rigourous because it is not so in my textbook. Also the math should be introductory calculus or anything below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Math:**

For mathematics you want something like Essential Mathematics for Economic Analysis by Sydsaeter et al. or Mathematics for Economists by Blume et al.

Both of the books have introductory calculus.

**Macro:**

For macroeconomics you can start with some undergraduate books like Mankiw Macroeconomics or Blanchard et al Macroeconomics: European Perspectives.

If you want something more advanced you will first need to learn more math than just introductory calculus. Both of the math books I recommended have more, if you can go over both of the math books you would be also ready to pick something like Romer Advanced macroeconomics, or depending on which branch of macroeconomics you are interested there might be more specific books (e.g. if you are interested in growth theory Acemoglu: Introduction to Modern Economic Growth is really good).

**Micro:**

On an undergraduate level you can use something like Frank Microeconomics and Behavior or first couple of chapters from Mankiw's principles of economics (the last chapters are also about macro so this covers both but not in as great detail as books that cover them separately).

Once you have good math skills you can advance to something like MWG: Microeconomic Theory, or Varian Microeconomic Analysis.